# Incrementing grails value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I have been working on a javascript function which doesnt make sense to me. I have this in my script:

```
    function increment(){
     alert("incremented number ${inc++ }\n");
     }
```

and I have this in my controller to return the inc value:

```
    def test(){
    def inc = 1;
    [inc:inc]
    }
```

And in the same gsp, I have this:

```
   <button onclick="increment()">click me</button>
```

Now when I first click the button, an alert will display with the variable inc being incremented to 2. Now when I click it again, it doesnt increment any more, it stays 2 even how much you click it. It doesnt increment anymore. How can I make this to increment every time I click the button?

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change the value of a variable you define in Grails via Javascript.

Grails works as follows: upon a request, the corresonding script is found and executed. The script returns an HTML document, possibly including Javascript functions, and sends the document to the browser.

Your Javascript function works then in the browser. It cannot inform Grails to do the increment.

UPDATE: If you want to increase the value every time your clieck the button, you'll have to define a variable in Javascript and increase this variable upon button being clicked.

Comment: So how can I make it atleast increment everytime I click the button?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it works. Now my problem is how to assign this value to the grails variable :(

Comment: Well, you have to make a call to the server upon the button being clicked. For instance, you can define a new action of your web app (in Grails), and make `onclick` of your button call this action.